# Create a simple video using Adobe After Effects from command line

Tags: javascript, video-processing, after-effects

I need to create a simple video where I can add a red colour background and write the text "Hello World" using Adobe After Effects Scripting.

The purpose is that I need to create video by writing a command in CMD.

Can this be done ? and Can someone show me an example.

So finally I want to able to create a video using the command prompt similar to this.  `C:> afterfx.exe red HelloWorld` And a video should be created with a red background and the text on the video

I have done [my research and only this link tells this is possible](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-run-AfterEffects-on-a-server-to-render-videos-on-the-fly-with-images-and-text). I know this can be easily done with FFMPEG but I need to know how this is done with After Effects.

Comment: You may want to give FFMpeg a look.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/610903/how-can-i-create-a-video-file-from-a-set-of-jpg-images

Comment: @RickTakes I have already  done, but it doesn't have the functionality that Adobe AE can do.

Comment: You may have better luck at video.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SharonWatinsan This can be achieved with Templater for AE.  It has a command line interface.  You can see more information about the command line tools that Templater requires here:  https://github.com/dataclay/cli-tools